# Prevent Firefox from suspending JavaScript execution in background tab

Tags: firefox

I have a game running in a Firefox 56 tab. Whenever I switch to another tab, the game's execution is halted. I suppose this is Firefox trying to save CPU time and energy. Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 2):

Firefox shouldn't halt it completely but it does e.g. limit setTimout and setInterval to a minimum of one second. Maybe the game doesn't handle that well, or maybe the game is designed to halt when in background.

Relevant links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Background_Tasks_API
- https://content.pivotal.io/blog/chrome-and-firefox-throttle-settimeout-setinterval-in-inactive-tabs